# loupe effect css

Tags: javascript, html, css

Do you think it's possible to create a loupe/magnifying-glass effect with css / Html5 ?

I found an interesting application [here](http://www.netzgesta.de/loupe/) but it's based in JS.

Comment: No. Why don't you want to use JS (even your question is tagged with that)?

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot do this using only CSS / HTML5.
You need the javascript to create the drag effect and calculate the portion of the zoomed image that will be displayed inside the magnifying glass thingy.

You could create something **vaguely similar** by applying a CSS3 scale transformation on hover for the image and fiddling around with maybe some fixed divs and hidden overflows but if you want something like in that link you posted, javascript is the way to go.